no gutter space for a particular div
refer the divs with text "why no gutter space for this?". why is there no gutter space between these two particular divs inside a row? I've tried adding gx-2 to the parent row but it's still not adding space between those 2 columns. run the code snippet on the full page to see issue better.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row text-white">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-8 bg-dark opacity-25">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
                            voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla fugiat, cum quis ut! Pariatur esse, dolor at omnis
                            ducimus magni aperiam.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="col-md-12 bg-dark opacity-25">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
                                voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 bg-dark opacity-25">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
                                voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-5 bg-dark opacity-25 ">
                        <p>why no gutter space for this? </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 bg-dark opacity-25 ">
                        <p>why no gutter space for this?  </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 bg-dark opacity-25">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat voluptatum
                    rerum,
                    sequi asperiores nulla </p>
            </div>
        </div>




You're playing around a lot with padding there, but you're much better off using the gap property. Background color fills the padding area, so the visual gap is only working on the elements with padding but no background color.

Avoid using background colors in Bootstrap columns, they cover the gutter space between columns.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row g-2 text-white">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
          voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla fugiat, cum quis ut! Pariatur esse, dolor at omnis
          ducimus magni aperiam. 8</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row g-2">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
              voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla 12 </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat
              voluptatum rerum, sequi asperiores nulla 12 </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">why no gutter space for this? </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">why no gutter space for this?  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="bg-dark opacity-25">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, ab neque ex repellat voluptatum
      rerum, sequi asperiores nulla 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>



